# CSS minimal element distance from browser window?

Tags: css, position

Is there something like min-left property, I mean can I set element minimal distance from the left browser side so it won't go beyond that? Something similar to width and min-width property..

Answer (score 0):

I think you should wrap your elements in some div giving it a fixed padding. Or some other element insertion, but you won't do it without markup changing. The exception is if you have just text with align:not_where_you_need_margin, then it's just padding of the carrying container.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no CSS that can do that. You can use relative positioning and add an html element (spacer) before the element that you want to have a min-left property. Now you can give the spacer a min-width. Eg:

```
div {
    height:20px;
    float:left;
}
#your_div {
    background: green;
    width:20px;
}
#spacer {
    background: blue;
    width:50%;
    min-width: 100px;
}

<div id="spacer"></div>
<div id="your_div"></div>
```